# Recurrence with cases

Tags: recurrence-relations

$\def\left{\operatorname{left}}\def\right{\operatorname{right}}$I have the following recurrence with cases:
$$
    p(l, r, s) = 0.5 \cdot \left(l, r, s)
               + 0.5 \cdot \right(l, r, s)
$$
where:
$$
    \left(l, r, s) = \begin{cases} p(l - s, r, 2s)  & s \le l\\
                            1                 & l < s \le l + w\\
                    0                 & l + w < s\end{cases} $$

$$    \right(l, r, s) = \begin{cases} p(l, r - s, 2 s)  & s \le r\\
                    1                  & r < s \le r + w\\
                    0                & r + w < s\end{cases}$$

Is there a way to solve this recurrence analytically?

I'm interested in finding a solution for parameters such that $l = r = k$, $s = 1$ and $w = f\cdot k$, where $f \in (0, 1)$.

If not, is there a way to solve this analytically for a fixed $k$?

Comment: What did you mean by $f \in \langle 0, 1 \rangle$? I replaced it with $f \in (0,1)$, was that right?

Comment: I meant that `w` is some fraction of `k`, that is `w` is in the interval `(0, 1)`. Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: Please use `$...$` for mathematical text.